# rails Model.create(:attr=>"value") returns model with uninitialized fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is really stumping me.  The process works fine if I go about it with `#new` and then `#save`, but `#create` returns a model instance with all the fields set to `nil`.

**e.g:**
Unexpected behavior:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > EmailDefault.create(:description=>"hi")
 => #<EmailDefault id: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Expected behaviour:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > e = EmailDefault.new
 => #<EmailDefault id: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > e.description = "hi"
 => "hi"
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > e.save
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > EmailDefault.last
 => #<EmailDefault id: 4, description: "hi", created_at: "2011-02-27 22:25:33", updated_at: "2011-02-27 22:25:33">
```

What am I doing wrong?

--update--
Turns out I was mis-using `attr_accessor`.  I wanted to add some non-database attributes, so I did it with:

`attr_accessible :example_to, :cc_comments`

which is wrong, and caused the situation @Heikki mentioned.  What I need to do is:

`attr_accessor :example_to, :cc_comments`

Comment: Maybe validation does not pass ? Or a callback unsets the attribute?

Comment: If you post the code for your `EmailDefault` model that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to white list those properties with attr_accessible to enable mass-assignment.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

--edit

By default all attributes are available for mass-assignment. If attr_accessible is used then mass-assignment will work only for those attributes. Attr_protected works the opposite way ie. those attributes will be protected from mass-assignment. Only one should be used at a time. I prefer the white listing with attr_accessible.

Comment: Mostly right, amend your answer and I'll mark yours correct.  If you use `attr_accessible` for any attributes it is required for all attributes you want mass assign.  If you don't use it all, you don't need it.