# Rails association.create and association.create! returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm just throwing this out there because I really can't figure this out. When I call for instance `user.articles.create! { title: 'blah' }` nil is returned but the object is created. I've not seen anything like this before and was wondering if someone else has?

I've tried rails 3.2.13 and 3.2.12 and they both do the same thing.

**EDIT**

In active record both create and create! ends up IN THIS METHOD that is supposed to return the record or throw an exception.

```rb
def create_record(attributes, options, raise = false, &block)
  unless owner.persisted?
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved, "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved"
  end

  if attributes.is_a?(Array)
    attributes.collect { |attr| create_record(attr, options, raise, &block) }
  else
    transaction do
      add_to_target(build_record(attributes, options)) do |record|
        yield(record) if block_given?
        insert_record(record, true, raise)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Weird indeed, can you try in `rails c`, just to confirm?

Comment: when object is created `create!` returns created object otherwise raise an error, but it never returns `nil`.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminSinclaire it worked fine in development mode and like suggested it had to do with factory_girl.

Comment: And thanks to the editors for removing the parts with me being pissed of from the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) mimic the actual object you're dealing with through your predefined factory. Therefor `User#articles` might not return what you think it is when called on a factory.

Changing

```
user.articles.create! { title: 'blah' }
```

to

```
create(:article, user: user, title: 'blah')
```

should enforce the association through Factory Girl's interface.

Comment: Yup that works, for some reason something changed in how we use factory_girl

Answer (score 2):

I had the same symptom, and this question is the only relevant hit that I could find. I'll throw my solution into the mix in case it helps anyone else.

The code worked in real life, and only failed under `rspec`. All the troubleshooting I did made no sense, pointing to `create!` being broken, which I never believed.

As it turns out, I was mocking `create!` so it never got called. Adding `.and_call_original` to my mock solved the problem.

My model was something like this: (not really...but compatible with this answer)

```
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :seats

  def create_seats(seat_count)
    seat_count.times { Seat.create!(flight: self) }
    seats.each(&:raise_seatback_and_lock_tray)
  end
```

And my test was:

```
it 'creates enough empty seats' do
  expect(Seat).to receive(:create!).twice
  flight.create_seats(2)
end
```

The expectation was met (confirmed manually), but an error was raised:

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `raise_seatback_and_lock_tray=' for nil:NilClass
```

Changing my mock to allow `create!` to actually be called solved the problem:

```
it 'creates enough empty seats' do
  expect(Seat).to receive(:create!).twice.and_call_original
  flight.create_seats(2)
end
```

This now passed:

```
    creates enough empty seats
1 example, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is something going on with your `attr_accessible` or `attr_accessor` in your `Article` class. I you might have not included the `user_id` or something else...

There is also a similar question here: [rails Model.create(:attr=>"value") returns model with uninitialized fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136521/rails-model-createattr-value-returns-model-with-uninitialized-fields)

Answer (score -1):

If you are expecting the object to be returned use

```
user.articles.create { title: 'blah' }
```

Why some methods have bang (!), you can read this topic
[Why are exclamation marks used in Ruby methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612189/why-are-exclamation-marks-used-in-ruby-methods)

Comment: The create! method creates the object or raises an exception if it fails it never returns nil. create without bang returns the object with id nil if it fails (doesn't throw exception)

Comment: thanks for downvote. but nil/false is better than exception. you can handle like `if user.articles.create { title: 'blah' } ...`.